# Overloading operator= between customized classes int2_, float2_ and double2_ for CUDA application

Tags: c++, templates, cuda, operator-overloading

I'm defining the classes `int2_`, `float2_`, and `double2_` to deal with complex arithmetics in C++ and CUDA. I want to overload the operator `=` for mixed assignments of objects of the above classes and of the `int`, `float` and `double` types.

My implementation is the following:

```
class float2_;
class double2_;

class int2_ {

    public:
        int x;
        int y;

        int2_() : x(), y() {}

        __host__ __device__ inline const int2_& operator=(const int a)          { x = a;            y = 0.;         return *this; }
        __host__ __device__ inline const int2_& operator=(const float a)        { x = (int)a;       y = 0.;         return *this; }
        __host__ __device__ inline const int2_& operator=(const double a)       { x = (int)a;       y = 0.;         return *this; }
        __host__ __device__ inline const int2_& operator=(const int2_ a)        { x = a.x;          y = a.y;        return *this; }
        __host__ __device__ inline const int2_& operator=(const float2_ a);
        __host__ __device__ inline const int2_& operator=(const double2_ a);
};

class float2_ {

    public:
        float x;
        float y;

        float2_() : x(), y() {}

        __host__ __device__ inline const float2_& operator=(const int a)        { x = (float)a;     y = 0.;         return *this; }
        __host__ __device__ inline const float2_& operator=(const float a)      { x = a;            y = 0.;         return *this; }
        __host__ __device__ inline const float2_& operator=(const double a)     { x = (float)a;     y = 0.;         return *this; }
        __host__ __device__ inline const float2_& operator=(const int2_ a)      { x = (float)a.x;   y = (float)a.y; return *this; }
        __host__ __device__ inline const float2_& operator=(const float2_ a)    { x = a.x;          y = a.y;        return *this; }
        __host__ __device__ inline const float2_& operator=(const double2_ a);
};

class double2_ {

    public:
        double x;
        double y;

        double2_() : x(), y() {}

        __host__ __device__ inline const double2_& operator=(const int a)       { x = (double)a;    y = 0.;         return *this; }
        __host__ __device__ inline const double2_& operator=(const float a)     { x = (double)a;    y = 0.;         return *this; }
        __host__ __device__ inline const double2_& operator=(const double a)    { x = a;            y = 0.;         return *this; }
        __host__ __device__ inline const double2_& operator=(const int2_ a)     { x = (double)a.x;  y = (double)a.y;return *this; }
        __host__ __device__ inline const double2_& operator=(const float2_ a)   { x = (double)a.x;  y = (double)a.y;return *this; }
        __host__ __device__ inline const double2_& operator=(const double2_ a)  { x = a.x;          y = a.y;        return *this; }

};

__host__ __device__ inline const int2_& int2_::operator=(const float2_ a)           { x = (int)a.x;             y = (int)a.y;       return *this; }
__host__ __device__ inline const int2_& int2_::operator=(const double2_ a)      { x = (int)a.x;             y = (int)a.y;       return *this; }
__host__ __device__ inline const float2_& float2_::operator=(const double2_ a)  { x = (float)a.x;           y = (float)a.y;     return *this; }
```

However, I receive a compilation error in the kernel

```
template <class A, class T1, class T2>
__global__ inline void evaluation_matrix(T1 *data_, const Expr<A,T2> e, int NumElements)
{
    const int i = blockDim.x * blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x;
    if(i < NumElements) data_[i] = e[i];
}
```

when `e` is an expression. The error message is

```
calling a __host__ function("float2_::float2_") from a __global__  
function("evaluation_matrix<BinExpr<const float *, const float2_ *, CudaOpSum, float2_> 
, double2_, float2_> ") is not allowed
```

In this case, `data_` is a `double2_` object and `e` is a `float2_` expression.

I have no problem in dealing with any of the `int`, `float`, `double`, `int2_`, `float2_` or `double2_` type or class for `data_`. I even receive no error message when `e` is an expression of `int`, `float` or `double` type. The only problem arises when `e` is of class `int2_`, `float2_` or `double2_`.

Any help? Thank you.

**WORKING SOLUTION FOLLOWING ARNE MERTZ'S ANSWER**

```
class float2_;
class double2_;

class int2_ {

    public:
        int x;
        int y;

        __host__ __device__ int2_() : x(), y() {}

        __host__ __device__ inline const int2_& operator=(const int a)          { x = a;            y = 0.;         return *this; }
        __host__ __device__ inline const int2_& operator=(const float a)        { x = (int)a;       y = 0.;         return *this; }
        __host__ __device__ inline const int2_& operator=(const double a)       { x = (int)a;       y = 0.;         return *this; }
        __host__ __device__ inline const int2_& operator=(const int2_ a)        { x = a.x;          y = a.y;        return *this; }
        __host__ __device__ inline const int2_& operator=(const float2_ a);
        __host__ __device__ inline const int2_& operator=(const double2_ a);
};

class float2_ {

    public:
        float x;
        float y;

        __host__ __device__ float2_() : x(), y() {}

        __host__ __device__ inline const float2_& operator=(const int a)        { x = (float)a;     y = 0.;         return *this; }
        __host__ __device__ inline const float2_& operator=(const float a)      { x = a;            y = 0.;         return *this; }
        __host__ __device__ inline const float2_& operator=(const double a)     { x = (float)a;     y = 0.;         return *this; }
        __host__ __device__ inline const float2_& operator=(const int2_ a)      { x = (float)a.x;   y = (float)a.y; return *this; }
        __host__ __device__ inline const float2_& operator=(const float2_ a)    { x = a.x;          y = a.y;        return *this; }
        __host__ __device__ inline const float2_& operator=(const double2_ a);
};

class double2_ {

    public:
        double x;
        double y;

        __host__ __device__ double2_() : x(), y() {}

        __host__ __device__ inline const double2_& operator=(const int a)       { x = (double)a;    y = 0.;         return *this; }
        __host__ __device__ inline const double2_& operator=(const float a)     { x = (double)a;    y = 0.;         return *this; }
        __host__ __device__ inline const double2_& operator=(const double a)    { x = a;            y = 0.;         return *this; }
        __host__ __device__ inline const double2_& operator=(const int2_ a)     { x = (double)a.x;  y = (double)a.y;return *this; }
        __host__ __device__ inline const double2_& operator=(const float2_ a)   { x = (double)a.x;  y = (double)a.y;return *this; }
        __host__ __device__ inline const double2_& operator=(const double2_ a)  { x = a.x;          y = a.y;        return *this; }

};

__host__ __device__ inline const int2_& int2_::operator=(const float2_ a)           { x = (int)a.x;             y = (int)a.y;       return *this; }
__host__ __device__ inline const int2_& int2_::operator=(const double2_ a)      { x = (int)a.x;             y = (int)a.y;       return *this; }
__host__ __device__ inline const float2_& float2_::operator=(const double2_ a)  { x = (float)a.x;           y = (float)a.y;     return *this; }
```

Comment: I think you need an explicitly defined device copy constructor to make this work.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment. Following Arne Mertz answer, I have added the `__host__ __device__` keywords to the `int2_`, `float2_` and `double2_` constructors and it worked. Are you meaning this? Are there more efficient (in terms of computational speed) solutions? Again, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the error says you cannot call `__host__` functions (in this case the constructor of your `float2_` class) from a `__global__` function. At first sight, that has nothing to do with the operators, since they are not mentioned in the error message. But if you have a closer look, there is `data_[i] = e[i]`.

**Attention:** wild guesses here, since you don't show all of the relevant code:

I guess `e[i]` gives a reference to a part of the expression, in this case of type `float2_`.
You are assigning that `e[i]` to a `double2_`, and the corresponding assignment operator is your `double2_::__host__ __device__ inline const double2_& operator=(const float2_ a)` which - apart from needlessly and unconventionally returning a const reference, takes that `float2_` *by value*, so the compiler has to copy `e[i]`, by a copy constructor wich seems to be declared with `__host__`. Apparently from the compiler message, it's not allowed to call `__host__` from `__global__` functions.

A solution would be to either declare the constructor `__global__` or to let the `op=` take its parameter by (const) reference, so the copy constructor does not need to be called. However, since the `operator=` itself is declared `__host__`, you probably get the same error due to that call as well.

I have no idea about cuda and don't know anything more about `__host__` and `__global__` than that error message told me, but hopefully I could give you a hint what might be wrong with the code.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer and very good deduction. I just added the `__host__ __device__` keywords to the `int2_`, `float2_` and `double2_` constructors and it worked. I have edited my post indicating the working solution. I also tried to use, for example, `__host__ __device__ inline const double2_& operator=(const float2_& a)` as I understood is your alternative solution, but I received the same error msg. One more question: why do you say that returning a const reference is needless and unusual? Thank you very much.

Comment: The usual return type of `T::operator=` is `T&`. If you are assigning to an object, you obviously modify that object. Making the reference to that recently modified object const is a bit of a contradiction. However, I actually can't make up an example where that makes much of a difference, since expressions modifying an asigned-to object look a bit awkward: `(a=b).foo();` or `++(a=b)` just look plain wrong. So it's mostly a matter of taste; an `op=` returning a ref to const ist just unusual.

Comment: Perhaps if I'm dealing with matrices as objects and want to manipulate the objects within mathematical expressions I would allow to modify the objects only within expressions and forbid methods to alter the matrix elements. By returning a constant reference I should have just this effect (e.g., avoiding something like you mentioned `(a=b).foo();`), right?

Comment: Yes, but that would disallow only the ugly expression. Doing the two operations in a sequence would still be possible: `a=b; a.foo();`

Comment: Perhaps a good reason to avoid the `const` keyword would be to enable move semantics? See for example [Move semantics and rvalue references in C++11](http://www.cprogramming.com/c++11/rvalue-references-and-move-semantics-in-c++11.html)?